# Fatal error when emailing specific participant list

Tags: email, participants, drupal-6

I get the following fatal error when trying to send an email (under 50 addresses) to a list of participants for one specific event. I can successfully email a participant list from another event.

I'm using CiviCRM 5.36.1 with Drupal 6 (Pressflow 6.56).

I'd really appreciate any ideas how to fix this.

````
$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => exceptionHandler ) [code] => -3 [message] => DB Error: constraint violation [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) VALUES ( 8527 , 45914 , 'b22a018b6ac6959f' ) [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`purcosacoza`.`civicrm_mailing_event_queue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mailing_event_queue_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)] [type] => DB_Error [user_info] => INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) VALUES ( 8527 , 45914 , 'b22a018b6ac6959f' ) [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`purcosacoza`.`civicrm_mailing_event_queue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mailing_event_queue_contact_id` FOREIGN KEY (`contact_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_contact` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)] [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: constraint violation" code=-3 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler prefix="" info="INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) VALUES ( 8527 , 45914 , 'b22a018b6ac6959f' ) [nativecode=1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`purcosacoza`.`civicrm_mailing_event_queue`, CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_mailing_event_queue_contact_id```


BACKTRACE

```Message  $backTrace = #0 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(942): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE) #1 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(922): CRM_Core_Error::exceptionHandler(Object(DB_Error)) #2 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB.php(998): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: constraint violation", -3, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) V...") #3 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-3, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) V...") #4 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src/PEAR.php(223): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -3, 16, (Array:2), "INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) V...", "DB_Error", TRUE) #5 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1928): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7)) #6 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-3, NULL, NULL, "INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) V...", "1452 ** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pu...") #7 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError() #8 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/pear/db/DB/common.php(1234): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) V...") #9 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) V...") #10 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1245): DB_DataObject->_query("INSERT INTO `civicrm_mailing_event_queue` (`job_id` , `email_id` , `hash` ) V...") #11 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(639): DB_DataObject->insert() #12 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Event/BAO/Queue.php(41): CRM_Core_DAO->save() #13 [...]/static/files/purcosa.co.za.files/civicrm/ext/com.pesc.sparkpost/sparkpost.php(280): CRM_Mailing_Event_BAO_Queue::create((Array:3)) #14 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(275): sparkpost_civicrm_alterMailParams((Array:9), "singleEmail") #15 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook/DrupalBase.php(74): CRM_Utils_Hook->runHooks((Array:165), "civicrm_alterMailParams", 2, (Array:9), "singleEmail", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) #16 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(172): CRM_Utils_Hook_DrupalBase->invokeViaUF(2, (Array:9), "singleEmail", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_alterMailParams") #17 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(214): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher::delegateToUF(Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent), "hook_civicrm_alterMailParams", Object(Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher)) #18 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php(44): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch((Array:1), "hook_civicrm_alterMailParams", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent)) #19 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/Core/CiviEventDispatcher.php(129): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_alterMailParams", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent)) #20 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(167): Civi\Core\CiviEventDispatcher->dispatch("hook_civicrm_alterMailParams", Object(Civi\Core\Event\GenericHookEvent)) #21 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Hook.php(1218): CRM_Utils_Hook->invoke((Array:2), (Array:9), "singleEmail", NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, "civicrm_alterMailParams") #22 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Mail.php(179): CRM_Utils_Hook::alterMailParams((Array:9), "singleEmail") #23 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(639): CRM_Utils_Mail::send((Array:9)) #24 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(298): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::sendReminderEmail(Object(Civi\Token\TokenRow), Object(CRM_Core_DAO_ActionSchedule), "50360") #25 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/ActionSchedule.php(372): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::sendMailings(3, "20210505200124") #26 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(207): CRM_Core_BAO_ActionSchedule::processQueue("20210505200124", (Array:2)) #27 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_send_reminder((Array:2)) #28 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(149): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8)) #29 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8)) #30 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1)) #31 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(134): civicrm_api("Job", "send_reminder", (Array:1)) #32 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/JobManager.php(66): CRM_Core_JobManager->executeJob(Object(CRM_Core_ScheduledJob)) #33 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/v3/Job.php(118): CRM_Core_JobManager->execute(FALSE) #34 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Provider/MagicFunctionProvider.php(89): civicrm_api3_job_execute((Array:2)) #35 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(149): Civi\API\Provider\MagicFunctionProvider->invoke((Array:8)) #36 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(81): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest((Array:8)) #37 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/api/api.php(22): Civi\API\Kernel->runSafe("Job", "execute", (Array:2)) #38 [...]/static/import/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/drush/civicrm.drush.inc(1361): civicrm_api("Job", "execute", (Array:2)) #39 [...]/tools/drush/includes/command.inc(422): drush_civicrm_api("Job.execute", "auth=0") #40 [...]/tools/drush/includes/command.inc(231): _drush_invoke_hooks((Array:37), (Array:2)) #41 [...]/tools/drush/includes/command.inc(199): drush_command("Job.execute", "auth=0") #42 [...]/tools/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/BaseBoot.php(67): drush_dispatch((Array:37)) #43 [...]/tools/drush/includes/preflight.inc(67): Drush\Boot\BaseBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch() #44 [...]/tools/drush/drush.php(12): drush_main() #45 {main}
````

Comment: any chance you have a munted email address for a participant? more like what Demerit is suggesting, but since you are saying 'works for A but not B' then perhaps something wrong with an address in Group B

Comment: Good idea on the email addresses - yesterday I had a look through the list and they looked OK, but its a small list of 21 contacts so a delete/replace of each address will determine if that's the prob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the error for this problem, which was triggering an error for CiviEvent registrations and event reminders. Guidance from @Demerit and @petednz should have led me to it sooner.

The problem was caused by an email address with a 9-letter top level domain, and regex in sparkpost.php which assumes that top level domains are between 2 and 4 characters but see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains#Brand_top-level_domains .

I changed the regex from 2,4 to 2,24 and the problem is resolved.

Comment: good catch Davy

Comment: ....and just found that the problem is not fully resolved. While registrations are now working the event reminders are triggering a 'DB Error: constraint violation'.

Clearly some more digging needed :-(

Answer (score 0):

What version of [that sparkpost extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sparkpost-civicrm-integration) do you have? It looks pretty old. It's not inserting a contact_id when it needs to. Maybe need to update to latest master version from github manually.

Comment: It has the latest version - and the site pumps out thousands of emails all the time without any overt problems. 
But I'll try your idea to instal the gihub master and see if that helps.